# How do I keep track on who wins in the rounds to show at the end?

Tags: python

I think that I would have to use a tuple or a list but I'm very new to Python so I do not know how to implement it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```py
for i in range(4):
    # Take user input
    coin_side = input('Heads or Tails ? Type H or T > ')
    coin_side = coin_side.upper()
    
    # Generate random number for players
    player_1 = random.choice(['H', 'T'])
    player_2 = random.choice(['H', 'T'])
    
    print('Player 1 has tossed ', player_1)
    print('Player 2 has tossed ', player_2)
    
    if coin_side == player_1 and coin_side == player_2:
        print('Player 1 wins')
        print('Player 2 wins')
    elif coin_side == player_1:
        print('Player 1 wins')
    elif coin_side == player_2:
        print('Player 2 wins')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea that another variable is needed. The most simple way would be to just have a variable for each number of wins and update it where you're printing who wins. For example

```
p1_wins = 0
p2_wins = 0
for i in range(4):
    # Take user input
    coin_side = input('Heads or Tails ? Type H or T > ')
    coin_side = coin_side.upper()
    
    # Generate random number for players
    player_1 = random.choice(['H', 'T'])
    player_2 = random.choice(['H', 'T'])
    
    print('Player 1 has tossed ', player_1)
    print('Player 2 has tossed ', player_2)
    
    if coin_side == player_1 and coin_side == player_2:
        print('It's a tie!)
        p1_wins += 1
        p2_wins += 1
    elif coin_side == player_1:
        print('Player 1 wins')
        p1_wins += 1
    elif coin_side == player_2:
        print('Player 2 wins')
        p2_wins += 1
print(f'Player 1 had {p1_wins} wins and player 2 had {p2_wins}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track those wins you can use `list` for this purpose

```
winners = []
for i in range(4):
    # Take user input
    coin_side = input('Heads or Tails ? Type H or T > ')
    coin_side = coin_side.upper()

    # Generate random number for players
    player_1 = random.choice(['H', 'T'])
    player_2 = random.choice(['H', 'T'])

    print('Player 1 has tossed ', player_1)
    print('Player 2 has tossed ', player_2)

    if coin_side == player_1 and coin_side == player_2:
        print('Player 1 wins')
        print('Player 2 wins')
        winners.append('Both wins')
    elif coin_side == player_1:
        print('Player 1 wins')
        winners.append('Player 1 wins')
    elif coin_side == player_2:
        print('Player 2 wins')
        winners.append('Player 2 wins')
```

---

```
print(winners)
['Player 1 wins', 'Both wins', 'Both wins', 'Player 1 wins']
```

---

```
print(winners.count('Both wins'))

2 #Output
```